# iOS Share Extension - extract images from url

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I'm in the process of building a share extension that accepts anything as a URL, e.g a Safari webpage or another app that shares a URL (e.g Coursera)

I want to try and associate an image with the URL if at all possible even if the sharing app doesn't explicitly expose an image as one of it's share types.

if I take an article from Coursera as an example and then use Pinterest to share the images load fairly quick. As this is Coursera's native app I noticed they share text and a url.

In order to try to grab the images for this, I have to find the provider that is the public.url type, then load this url into a WKWebView and assign a scriptHandler. Wait for navigation to complete for the url. Then evaluate a javascript string that extracts the images and calls postMessage on my script handler with those values (I've also tried just returning the values from evaluateJavascriptString). This makes my extension seem very slow. e.g

```
let provider = urlProvider as! NSItemProvider // 

        provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeURL as String, options: nil) { (item, error) in

           if let url = item as? NSURL {

                let contentController = WKUserContentController()

                contentController.add(self, name: ScriptNames.GetImage.rawValue)
                let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
                config.userContentController = contentController
                self.wv = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0), configuration: config)
                self.wv?.navigationDelegate = self
                let req = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
                self.wv?.load(req)
                }
        }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
       //check for error other wise result actually calls userContentController
  })


    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
//get returned image urls
}
```

Then finally I have to create a Data object from these urls and instantiate a UIImage from data and display these back in collectionView cells

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let src:String = data[indexPath.row]
    print(src)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        let url = URL(string: src)
        let imgdata = try!  Data(contentsOf: url!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imgdata)
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

I know the data calls here can be cached using one of the many frameworks out there, but performance still seems much slower to Pinterest. I'm wondering if they actually pass the URL to their own server side and perform any functions there to retrieve images...

I looked into using a NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile but this only seems to run in Safari and not in native apps that share a url

Is there a better way to optimise this?

My allowed items has been set to the following in my plist - I'm wondering if this would need a custom predicate

```
  <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
```

Comment: You start three paragraphs with `Now`, and I don't understand your question. Are you saying that your extension works, but is too slow? How slow? In general if you are downloading media content (like any `UIImage`) synchronously, which you might be (you didn't post your code for this part), then it'll be slow. Load media asynchronously (see `GCD` ie. `DispatchQueue.global.async {`

Comment: So I've added the code that does the image loading, initially I wasn't doing it async and whilst this has improved performance, it's still a lot slower between 3-4 seconds than the Pinterest app when retrieving these images

Comment: @TommyBs, how did this end up working out - did you find a faster way to do it thank this?

Comment: I ended up writing my own web service that takes the url and finds the images and returns those to my app